# Creating and live-updating database without php (on Heroku)

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, database, heroku

I'm wondering if there's some way, using JS+nodejs, to create and to live- update a database.

I am in a bit of a time crunch and am very unfamiliar with PHP, and am having problems using PHP+Heroku. I am much more familiar with JS+nodejs. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: something like https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using meteor?

https://www.meteor.com/

Meteor runs on top of NodeJS and you can build apps with two way data binding ( database and front-end) using meteor. Plus It has support for Angular and React.

https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app

Alternatively you can build everything from scratch with NodeJS, some front-end framework and Socket.io.

Comment: thank you! so i'd be able to create a database within meteor, and be able to live update that database across browsers/users/etc?

Comment: Yes. Meteor supports Mongo. For a sample app : https://www.meteor.com/articles/todos-example-app